# Plot multiple different types of ggplots in one graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot multiple different ggplots (see code below) in one graph.

I thought this ought to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Rmisc)
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(12,0,1)
df <- data.frame(y=rep(y,3),age=rnorm(12,50,2),sex=c(rep("female",6),rep("male",6)),race=c(rep("black",3),rep("white",3),rep("other",3)))
df$sex <- as.factor(df$sex)
df$race <- as.factor(df$race)
covariates = c("age","sex","race")
ggplot_list <- vector(mode="list", length(covariates))
for(i in 1:length(covariates)){
  if(is.factor(df[,covariates[i]])){
    ggplot_list[[i]] <- ggplot(df, aes(x=df[,covariates[i]], y=df$y), environment = environment())+geom_boxplot()+geom_jitter()+labs(x = covariates[i],y="y")
  } else{
    ggplot_list[[i]] <- ggplot(df, aes(x=df[,covariates[i]], y=df$y), environment = environment())+geom_point(shape=1)+labs(x = covs[i],y="y")
  }
}
```

But:

```
multiplot(plotlist=ggplot_list,cols=length(covariates))
```

Help..

Gives:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `aes` you should only refer to column names, rather than including both data frame name and column name. You've already passed the data frame into `ggplot` (`ggplot(df,...)`) so `ggplot` already has access to the data frame columns inside its environment. Including the data frame inside `aes` subverts that by telling ggplot to go outside into the parent environment for the data frame. Here's a version of your code that does what it seems like you want. We use `aes_string` instead of `aes` so that we can pass the values of `covariates` as strings:

```
ggplot_list <- vector(mode="list", length(covariates))

for(i in 1:length(covariates)){
  if(is.factor(df[,covariates[i]])){
    ggplot_list[[i]] <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=covariates[i], y="y")) +
      geom_boxplot() + 
      geom_jitter() + 
      labs(x = covariates[i], y="y")
  } else{
    ggplot_list[[i]] <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=covariates[i], y="y")) +
      geom_point(shape=1) + 
      labs(x = covariates[i],y="y")
  }
}
```

Here's a more concise version:

```
# List to store plots
pl = list()

for (i in covariates) {

  # Set up parts of plot that don't change
  pl[[i]] = ggplot(df, aes_string(x=i, y="y")) + labs(x = i)

  # Different handling for categorical and numeric x variable
  if (is.numeric(df[,i])) {
    pl[[i]] = pl[[i]] + geom_point(shape=1)
  } else {
    pl[[i]] = pl[[i]] + geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter(width=0.2) 
  }
}
```

You can also do this with `lapply` instead of a for loop:

```
pl = lapply(covariates, function(cc) { 

  # Set up parts of plot that don't change
  p = ggplot(df, aes_string(x=cc, y="y")) + labs(x = cc)

  # Different handling for categorical and numeric x variable
  if (is.numeric(df[, cc])) {
    p = p + geom_point(shape=1)
  } else {
    p = p + geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter(width=0.2) 
  }
})
```

To lay out the plots, use `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package (`plot_grid` from `cowplot` is another option, as pointed out by @JoshuaRosenberg):

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(grobs=pl, ncol=length(covariates))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `cowplot` (vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html)).

Once you have the `ggplot` objects, something like:

`plot_grid(plot_age, plot_gender, plot_race)`